# Am I correct? Subjective and Injective logic (my reasoning)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

So I am trying to prove:

> The function
> $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x, y) = x^3 - xy^2$ is surjective and injective.

###### Surjectivity:

To prove surjectivity, we need to show that for every $z$ in the codomain $\mathbb{R}$, there exists at least one pair $(x, y)$ in the domain $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x, y) = z$.

Given $f(x, y) = x^3 - xy^2$, we can say:
\begin{align}
x^3 - xy^2 &= z \\
x^3 &= z + xy^2 \\
x &= \sqrt[3]{z + xy^2}
\end{align}

Now, if we fix any $y$, we can choose $x = \sqrt[3]{z + xy^2}$, which will give us the desired $x$ for any $z$. The function is surjective.

###### Injectivity:

To prove injectivity, we need to show that for any $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ in the domain such that $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$, then $(x_1, y_1) = (x_2, y_2)$.

We can suppose $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$:
\begin{align}
x_1^3 - x_1y_1^2 &= x_2^3 - x_2y_2^2 \\
x_1^3 - x_2^3 &= x_1y_1^2 - x_2y_2^2 \\
(x_1 - x_2)(x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2) &= x_1(y_1^2 - y_2^2)
\end{align}

If $x_1 \neq x_2$, we could divide both sides by $(x_1 - x_2)$ to get:
$$
x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = y_1^2 - y_2^2
$$

But the left-hand side is a quadratic polynomial in $x$ and the right-hand side is a difference of squares implying the function cannot hold for all $x$, unless $x_1 = x_2$.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Isn't $f(0,0) = f(1,1)$?

Comment: "Now, if we fix any (y), we can choose (x=z+xy2−−−−−−√3), which will give us the desired ( x ) "  How?  If $x = \sqrt{z + xy^2}$.  What exactly is is $x$?  For example.  If $27$ we have $x=\sqrt{27 + xy^2}$ and we fix  $y = 2$ we have $x = \sqrt{27 + 4x}$.  So... what is $x$?

Comment: "But the left-hand side is a quadratic polynomial in x and the right-hand side is a difference of squares implying the function cannot hold for all x, unless x1=x2."  What difference does it make what form the numbers are written in? These aren't polynomials for all values but single instance of single values.  What if $x_1=x_2$ then $x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = 3$.  And what if $y_1=2$ and $y_2 = 1$.  Then $y_1^2 - y_2^2 = 3 = x_1^2+x_1x_2 + x_2^2$.

Comment: There can be no continuous injection of $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}$ into $\Bbb{R}$ (google "invariance of domain"). Your function cannot be injective.

Comment: "squares implying the function cannot hold for all x"  Who said anything about holding for all $x$?  We don't need it to hold for *all* $x$.  We only need it to hold for $x_1, x_2, y_2, y_1$.

Comment: Also note.  You did get that $x =\sqrt[3]{z + xy^2}$.  If the function were injective, that would mean there is one *one* possible value that $y$ can be.  You assumed we could fix $y$ to *anything* in your attempt at surjectivity.  If you *can* fix $y$ to anything the the function is certainly not injective.  We can set $y=0$ and get $x=\sqrt[3]x$. If we set $y=1$ we get $x=\sqrt[3]{z+x}$ probably has a solution. If it does then it can't be injective

Comment: The function $x\mapsto x^3$ is already surjective, so just take $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't injective:
$$f(x,y) = x^3 - xy^2 = x^3 - x(-y)^2 = f(x,-y).$$
And your proof of surjectivity is wrong: your $x = \sqrt[3]{z + xy^2}$ depends on $x$.

Comment: I believe you mean 'surjectivity' and not 'injectivity'.

Comment: @JulioPuerta, corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not injective. In fact, as $$f(x,y)=x^3-xy^2=x(x^2-y^2),$$

any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x=y$ verifies that $f(x,y)=0$.

It is, however, surjective: just notice that $f(x,0)=x^3$, which is by itself a surjective function.

Comment: Note: The proof of surjectivity (that $x=\sqrt[3]{z+xy^2}$ but if we fix $y=0$ we have $x=\sqrt[3]z3$) strongly implies the function is not injective as injectivity would require that if you fix $y$ to one thing and solve for $x$, then fixing $y$ to *anything* else would mean there is no solution.  Admitedly if we fix $y$ to $k$ it might not be clear what the solution to $x=\sqrt[3]{z+xk^2}$ actually is but to say there is *never* a solution is just too much.

Comment: I'm not that fond of the phrasing "which is by itself a surjective function". Of course, I know what you mean, but strictly speaking, $f(x,0)$ is just a number. Perhaps it would be better to say something like "Since $f(x,0)=x^3$ for all $x$, it follows that for all $z\in\mathbb R$, we have $f(\sqrt[3]{z},0)=z$, and so $f$ is surjective".

Comment: @Joe I believe we all know what the meaning of the phrase is. The objective of the answer is to expose a simpler reasoning to this 'trivial' question, not to give  a formal proof of the fact.

Comment: @JulioPuerta: Well, certainly any mathematician would be able to translate your sentence into a formal statement, but not necessarily a beginner. After all, if someone were completely fluent with logical reasoning, then they wouldn't need to ask this question in the first place. Added to this, what you actually mean is that the function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $\phi(x)=f(x,0)$ is surjective, but I could imagine a beginner not finding that obvious: you are implicitly fixing one argument of $f$ but not the other.

Comment: I don't think a beginner would be asking multivariate calculus questions, but that certainly depends on your concept of 'beginner' (while it is clearly true that this person is not fluent with this kind of reasoning)

Comment: @Joe: the statement that $x^3$ is a surjective function is hardly a contentious misuse of terminology. That's how I read what Julio wrote and I think that's how most people would read it.

Comment: @RobArthan: I agree that's how most people would read it (and that's how I read it); I just think it helps to be a bit more careful for elementary questions like this one. I don't even object to saying something like "$x^3$ is a surjective function" – the problem for me is that in this particular case the earlier part of the phrase is that $f(x,0)=x^3$, which is a statement about the values of $f$.

Comment: So we are using $x^3$ simultaneously to refer to the function $x\mapsto x^3$, and the particular value of $f$ at a certain point, which I think could be a little confusing to a beginner. Agree to disagree I guess.

Comment: @Joe: the traditional notation for functions definitely conflates $x^3$ and $x \mapsto x^3$. This should be immensely confusing, but it is what has been used and taught since time immemorial. I would strongly support replacing the traditional notations we use with precise notations that make variable binding constructs completely clear, but it isn't going to happen anytime soon.

Answer (score -1):

No continuous function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ can be injective because else, when composed with the continuous injection $i:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2,\;x\mapsto(x,0)$, by the theorem of [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), $(\operatorname{im}f)\times\{0\}=(i\circ f)(\Bbb R^2)$ would be an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$, which is clearly false.

More elementarily, your $f$ is not injective since $f(2,1)=f(\sqrt[3]6,0)$. I leave it to you to track down your mistake.

As for the surjectivity, a correct proof is: $\forall z\in\Bbb R\quad z=f(\sqrt[3]z,0)$. (Yours is not because your definition of $x = \sqrt[3]{z + xy^2}$ is circular.)